# Multi-class classification with discrete output: Which loss function and activation to choose?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, lstm, multiclass-classification, loss-function

I'm working with a multi-class classification problem, using Keras Sequential models. In my dataset, the output class has one of the following values: `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Yes, I have already tried one-hot-encoding the output and using `categorical_crossentropy` as a loss function and `softmax` in the output layer.

However, I don't think that softmax and categorical cross entropy is the right choice in my case. In my dataset, the output classes have a certain "discreteness" (or scale). Class `1` is the "worst" and class `5` is the "best".

Let's say if on a specific input the model predicts `2` and the true class is `1`, it's a much better prediction as when the model predicts class `5` and true class is `1`.

I would like, that the loss function would take these "minor errors" into consideration and not treat all errors the same way.

**To sum up, I'm wondering what my options are in terms of loss function and activation of the output layer for my given problem.**

UPDATE: I have now tried to use `mse` as a loss function and replace my output layer with this:

`model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))`

The new method produces much better results, but I'm still wondering if there are any other options for my problem. Maybe a custom loss function?

Comment: You can do [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) as you happen to have ordinal dependent variable.

Comment: This is an ordinal regression, not a classification. When you treat it as an ordinal regression, the process should make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Quadratic Kappa Metric loss function. This is a summary of what it actually does.

> A weighted Kappa is a metric which is used to calculate the amount of
>   similarity between predictions and actuals. A perfect score of 1.0 is
>   granted when both the predictions and actuals are the same. Whereas,
>   the least possible score is -1 which is given when the predictions are
>   furthest away from actuals. In our case, consider all actuals were 0's
>   and all predictions were 4's. This would lead to a QWKP score of -1.
>   The aim is to get as close to 1 as possible. Generally a score of 0.6+
>   is considered to be a really good score.

The detailed explanation can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/aroraaman/quadratic-kappa-metric-explained-in-5-simple-steps